# Why do I get blank spaces after splitting the string by dot?

Tags: java

I am trying to split a `String` by `.` :

```
String sentences[] = fileContent.split(".");
```

`fileContent` is a string that contains the complete text data from a file. In the file there are 4 sentences some separated by white space gaps.

When I print `sentences[n]` it gives a `blank` . Why is it so when `sentences.length` prints 95.

Data structured in `fileContent` looks like : *(no-meaning text)*

```
My name is suhail. His name is suhail.

He was playing with suhail. He is cool and loves suhail.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to **escape** the dot character, because `split()` expects a **regex** (regular expression), not a plain string:

```
String sentences[] = fileContent.split("\\.");
```

Comment: To get a token out of `Rose is a flower`, will I put it like : `split("\\ ")` ?

Comment: No. You have to scape the dot, because it represents a *special character* in regex. If you want to split by a single space, use `split(" ")`. If you want to split by *any whitespace* you can use `split("\\s+")`. I will recommend you to read about regex so you understand how to use it.

Comment: It'd be worth mentioning that a dot has special meaning in RegEx -- which is why it needs to be escaped -- while a space does not have special meaning -- which is why it doesn't need to be escaped.